# Android Studio get get Data from from Database to TextView

Tags: php, android, json

can I make the encoded json of my data not the format of this

```
{"tbl_accepted":[{"renterLat":"15.706376","renterLng":"121.065852"}]}
```

I only want to get is the values of the Lat and the Lng so I can display them in seperate textViews accordingly. And here is how I'm getting it.

```
private void getJSON(String url){
    class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
        protected String doInBackground(String... params){
            String uri = params[0];
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
            try{

                URL url = new URL(uri);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

                String json;
                while((json=bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                    sb.append(json+"\n");
                }
                return sb.toString().trim();
            }catch(Exception e){
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s){
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            tvLat.setText(s);
            Log.d(TAG,tvLat.getText().toString());
        }
    }
    GetJSON gj = new GetJSON();
    gj.execute(url);
}
```

## PHP

```
<?php
include_once("connection.php");
$where = '';
if (isset($_GET['renter'])){
$where = " WHERE renter like '%".addslashes($_GET['renter'])."%'";
}
$sql = "SELECT renterLat, renterLng FROM tbl_accepted ".$where." ORDER BY acceptedID DESC";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$json = array();

if(mysqli_num_rows($result)){

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

    $json['tbl_accepted'][]=$row;
}
}

mysqli_close($conn);
echo json_encode($json);

?>
```

Thanks in advance sirs.

Comment: @Selvin - I'll try to learn about the `org.json` that was stated as an answer on that question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting following string as a result in `onPostExecute`.

```
{"tbl_accepted":[{"renterLat":"15.706376","renterLng":"121.065852"}]}
```

Use `JSONObject` and `JSONArray` to convert the **JSON String** to **Object**.

To convert string to object your could would look something like this in `onPostExecute`.

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s){
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            JSONObject latObj=new JSONObject(s);
            JSONArray tbl_accepted=latObj.getJSONArray('tbl_accepted');
            tvLat.setText(tbl_accepted.getJSONObject(0).getString('renterLat'));
            Log.d(TAG,tvLat.getText().toString());
        }
```

Comment: on `tvLat.setText(tbl_accepted[0].getString("renterLat"));` the `tbl_accepted` has an error of `Array type expected; found: 'org.json.JSONArray'`

Comment: Sorry it should be `getJSONObject` instead, check the updated code.